# How to open a link in jQuery without the referral information

Tags: jquery

I need to open a link from within jQuery but i need to avoid sending the referral information. In shorter words, i need to simulate **rel="noreferrer"**

Is it feasible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think every browser out there automatically tacks this information onto all requests, and there's no way to directly modify it with JavaScript.

After scouring the web, you do have a couple of options though:

1. Launch the link from within a Flash application
2. Launch the link from within a Java applet
3. Run your URL through a referrer cloaker/spoofer service

All options are ugly and I wouldn't recommend them for usability reasons. I'm basing this off of an old Google Answers [question](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/77993.html), but I think the answers stand.

Answer (score 10):

A quick solution to do no-referer link open.

```
function open_link(url)
{
    instance = window.open("about:blank");
    instance.document.write("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url="+url+"\">");
    instance.document.close();
    return false;
}
```

Tested. Working in FF, IE, Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You might have jQuery write a link with the `rel` attribute set to `noreferrer`, then call it with `$(link_you_made).click()`.

Comment: This is an HTML5 feature, and I think only the latest Webkit browsers support it.

Comment: exactly, in chrome it works perfectly. ffx 3.6 not so much. IE... no way.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you mean by opening a link "from within jQuery", but setting `window.location` directly won't pass any referrer information.

So if you have a link that you want to pass no referral information you could do something like this:

```
$("a").click(function() { window.location = $(this).attr("href"); return false; });
```

**Edit**: Just did some testing & it looks like Firefox actually *does* pass referrer information through with a `window.location` change. So unfortunately this is not a complete/cross-browser solution...

Also as sczizzo points out in the comment below, there may be times where this won't be reliable (for example, I'm not sure if/how `click` fires when you middle click a link in Firefox to open it in a new tab).

Comment: I'm not sure this will work as expected. The browser may bypass jQuery's event handler altogether.

Comment: @sczizzo: You're right (see updated answer), but I don't think there's any fool-proof way of doing it (beyond Cory Larson's suggestion of using something like flash), and I think this is the simplest answer that will at least cover the *most* situations.

Comment: Knowing that window.location wont cut it is helpful, but this answer is super evolved, this is not a forum, but a Q&A site, consider rephrasing it. Thanks