# Triggering a click action of an <a href=url rel='noreferrer'> in the success of an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

In my ember application, I have a dialog box with 'OK' and 'Cancel' buttons. On clicking on 'OK', an action will be triggered in which an ajax request will be sent and in its success, a new tab with a certain url has to be opened. I tried triggering a click in the success of the ajax request, but the pop up gets blocked. Here I want to use an

```
    <a href=url rel='noreferrer'>
```

**rel='noreferrer'** because I want the new tab to occupy seperate browser memory and not that of the current window. Hence I cannot create an element with window.open() before the ajax request and then change the location(url) in the success of it. ( new tab opened using window.open() will occupy the memory of the window from which the new tab got triggered). It would really help if I could get a solution. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

While you are looking for a method to trigger a click action, it sounds like more broadly you are trying to create a `noreferrer` popup from inside of a `javascript` function.  I think this would be possible using a two-part approach:

1. Open a new popup using `window.open()` containing only a small script tag.  This will not trigger the popup blocker, though it would still be sharing the linking page's memory.
2. Use the script tag (inside the popup) to trigger an HTML meta redirect (which incorporates the `no-referer` option as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13824120/6395388).

Note that you cannot do this in a single step, as you can't do an HTML meta redirect into a new window, only the current window ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2852187/6395388)).

Comment: newTab.document.write("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url="+url+"\">"); does not work - new tab still occupies the memory of the window from which it was triggered @derekbrown